# Adding/subtracting date-time columns in data-frames

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

I have a data frame with two text columns which are essentially time-stamps columns namely BEFORE and AFTER and the format is 12/29/2016 4:29:00 PM. I want to compare if the gap between the BEFORE and AFTER time for each row is more than 5 minutes or not. Which package in R will allow subtraction between time stamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for extra packages, using base R you can achieve the date time comparison.

First coerce your character to a valid date time structure. Here I am using `POSIXct`:

```
d1= as.POSIXct("12/29/2016 4:29:00 PM",format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
d2= as.POSIXct("12/30/2016 5:29:00 PM",format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Then to get the difference in minutes you can use `difftime`:

```
difftime(d1,d2,units="mins")
```

Note the all those functions are vectorized So the same code will work with vectors.

#### manage PM/AM

to take care of PM/AM we should add %p to the format that should be used in conjonction with `%I` not `%H`:

```
d1= as.POSIXct("12/28/2016 11:53:00 AM",
         format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
d2= as.POSIXct("12/28/2016 12:03:00 PM",
         format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

difftime(d2,d1,units="mins")
## Time difference of 10 mins
```

for more help about date/time format you can read `?strptime`.

Comment: This seems to work except in case where the time changes from AM to PM and vice versa. Eg:

> d1= as.POSIXct("12/28/2016 11:53:00 AM",format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
> d2= as.POSIXct("12/29/2016 12:03:00 PM",format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
> difftime(d2,d1,units="mins")
Time difference of 1450 mins

Which is incorrect since we know that the actual difference is 10 mins. Its adding a full 24 hours or 1440 mins.
Why is this happening?